# Waiting for a script run through ssh to finish before moving on within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a script that looks somewhat like this:

```
command1
command2
ssh login@machine_with_lots_of_ram:~/script_that_needs_ram.sh
command4 output_file_from_above
```

where command 4 needs the output of the ssh command.

How do I tell the program to wait until the ssh script finishes before continuing?  or better yet, how do I set the ssh script running on the remote machine after command 1 and hold the program from running command 4 until it finishes?

Comment: Why do you think that it is isn't waiting?  What results have you seen?

Comment: Unless you are using a weird version of `ssh`, you've got a superfluous colon in your `ssh` line. It should be `ssh user@host command`, not `ssh user@host:command`. The latter looks like `scp` syntax...

Answer (score 9):

The SSH session will not exit until the command (script) has finished executing on the remote server.

Depending on whether the script outputs data to a file on the server or if it outputs data to standard output you can do one of two things.

1. If it outputs data to a file on the server:

   ```
   ssh user@host script.sh
   scp user@host:remote_output local_output
   process_output local_output
   ```

   This basically uses `scp` to copy the data over from the server to the local machine.
2. If it outputs data to standard output:

   ```
   ssh user@host script.sh >local_output
   process_output local_output
   ```

   This redirects the standard output of the script to a local file.

To set the program running first and then wait:

```
ssh user@host script.sh &

# do other stuff

wait
scp user@host:remote_output local_output
process_output local_output
```

or

```
ssh user@host script.sh >local_output &

# do other stuff

wait
process_output local_output
```

The `wait` will pause the script until the `ssh` command (which runs as a background process) exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture the output of the remote command, something like this should work:

```
command1
command2
ssh login@machine_with_lots_of_ram "~/script_that_needs_ram.sh" > remote_output.log
command4 remote_output.log
# optionally:  rm remote_output.log
```

If `command4` will take input from standard input, you can even:

```
ssh login@machine_with_lots_of_ram "~/script_that_needs_ram.sh" | command4
```